# Build Noir validations rules with map

Tags: validation, clojure, noir

I've got dynamically generated forms, so I was trying to validate them this way:

```
(defn valid? [media-id data] ;media-id it's just a number, data is the form input
  (let [fields (common/get-fields-to-show media-id)] ; list of strings (the field names)
    (map (fn [f]
           (vali/rule (vali/has-value? ((keyword f) data))
                      [(keyword f) "Write something!!"]))
         fields))
    (not (apply vali/errors? (map keyword fields))))
```

but it won't work. There's no exception or message at all, `valid?` is evaluated as `true` so the flow continues as if there were no errors although all fields are empty. I even tried `(vali/has-value? nil)` to force the error but nothing changes.

Experimenting, I removed the `map`, took two specific fields, build their rules "by hand" this way:

```
(defn valid? [media-id data]
  (let [fields (common/get-fields-to-show media-id)
        f1 (first fields)
        f2 (second fields)]
    (vali/rule (vali/has-value? ((keyword f1) data))
               [(keyword f1) "Testing"])
    (vali/rule (vali/has-value? ((keyword f2) data))
               [(keyword f2) "Testing"])
    (not (apply vali/errors? (map keyword fields))))
```

And it works perfectly for those lucky fields.

I suspect it has something to do with [the way noir.validation saves the errors](https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir/blob/master/src/noir/validation.clj#L82) (a dynamic declared thing), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `map` for sequence of operations. `map` is for transforming a sequence to something else. What you need to use is `doseq`

Instead of:

```
(map (fn [f]
           (vali/rule (vali/has-value? ((keyword f) data))
                      [(keyword f) "Write something!!"]))
         fields))
```

Use this:

```
(doseq [f fields]
    (vali/rule (vali/has-value? ((keyword f) data))
                          [(keyword f) "Write something!!"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

map returns a lazy seq. You can force evaluation by using doall:

```
(doall (map ...
```